# Denest $\sqrt{3+\sin\frac{\pi}{4}-4\cos\frac{\pi}{8}}$ in terms of possible trigonometric functions.

Tags: trigonometry, nested-radicals

As the title suggests, denest;
$$\sqrt{3+\sin\frac{\pi}{4}-4\cos\frac{\pi}{8}}$$
in terms of possible trigonometric functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c:=\cos\frac{\pi}{8}$ so your surd is $\sqrt{3+\cos\frac{\pi}{4}-4c}=\sqrt{2c^2-4c+2}=(1-c)\sqrt{2}$, which you can freel to rewrite e.g. as $\sqrt{8}\sin^2\frac{\pi}{16}$. But you can rewrite it without trigonometry at all, since $c=\sqrt{\frac{1+1/\sqrt{2}}{2}}$.